# CAShapeLayer Slow User Interaction

Tags: uikit, core-animation, quartz-graphics, cgpath, cashapelayer

I have a CAShapeLayer and it has to do a simple task of moving on the screen, guided by the user's finger.

The problem is that the movement is too slow. The layer does move, but there is a lag and it feels slow.

I have another test app where an UIImage is moved and there is no lag at all and the image moves instantly.

What can I do to overcome this?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{  

    currentPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

}



- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{


    CGPoint activePoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(activePoint.x - currentPoint.x,activePoint.y - currentPoint.y);
    curLayer.position = CGPointMake(shapeLayer.position.x+newPoint.x,shapeLayer.position.y+newPoint.y); 
    currentPoint = activePoint;

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keep in mind that when you set the position on a layer (assuming it's not the root layer of a UIView on which actions are disabled by default), it implicitly *animates* to the new position, which takes 0.25 seconds. If you want to make it snappier, temporarily disable actions on the layer like this:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
  CGPoint activePoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
  CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(activePoint.x - 
                              currentPoint.x,activePoint.y - currentPoint.y);

  [CATransaction begin];
  [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
  curLayer.position = CGPointMake(shapeLayer.position.x + 
                             newPoint.x, shapeLayer.position.y + newPoint.y);
  [CATransaction commit];
  currentPoint = activePoint;
}
```

This should cause it to jump to the new position rather than animate. If that doesn't help, then let me take a look at your layer init code so I can see what properties and dimensions it has. Properties such as cornerRadius, for example, can affect performance.

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for months now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try setting [`shouldRasterize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shouldRasterize) to `YES` on your `CAShapeLayer`, particularly if it is usually drawn at the same scale. If your app runs on high-DPI devices, you may also need to set [`rasterizationScale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/rasterizationScale) to match the layer’s `contentsScale`.

While rasterizing your shape can make it faster to move the shape around, you’ll probably want to temporarily disable rasterization while you’re animating the layer’s path or size.